# Dynamically dependent choice form fields in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am new to django and what I am trying to do is to link two fields in a django form. First field contains choices as:

```
States = (('1', ('solid')), ('2', ('liquid')), ('3', ('gas')))
StatesFiels = forms.ChoiceField(choices= States)
```

And second field substances names:

```
Substances = (('1', ('benzene')), ('2', ('water')), ('3', ('salt')))....
SubstancesFiels = forms.ChoiceField(choices= Subsances)
```

How can I make that the second field provides as the options only e.g. "benzene" and "water" if in the first field the option "liquid" is selected?